# Mongoose expression type doesn't support Number, Boolean, or ObjectId types while aggregating

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have this query:

```
const match: PipelineStage.Match = {
      $match: {
        deleted: false,
        provinceId: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.provinceId),
      },
    };
    const query: PipelineStage[] = [match];
    const cities = await cityModel.aggregate(query);
```

But the problem is neither boolean nor ObjectId is supported by type Expression in the type Match. So I have to use an expression to have a simple match for the type Boolean.

**Match interface:**

```
export namespace PipelineStage {
    export interface Match {
      $match: Expression | Record<string, Expression>;
    }
}
```

The error I receive:

> error TS2352: Conversion of type '{ $match: { deleted: boolean; provinceId: ObjectId; }; }[]' to type 'PipelineStage[]' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
> Type '{ $match: { deleted: boolean; provinceId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId; }; }' is not comparable to type 'PipelineStage'.
> Type '{ $match: { deleted: boolean; provinceId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId; }; }' is not comparable to type 'Match'.
> Types of property '$match' are incompatible.
> Type '{ deleted: boolean; provinceId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId; }' is not comparable to type 'Expression | Record<string, Expression>'.
> Type '{ deleted: boolean; provinceId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId; }' is not comparable to type 'Record<string, Expression>'.
> Property 'deleted' is incompatible with index signature.
> Type 'boolean' is not comparable to type 'Expression'.

So the question is how can I use simple matching for a boolean, number, or ObjectId in TypeScript aggregate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Filterquery` as the match object type solved the problem.

```
const match: PipelineStage.Match = {
  $match: {
    deleted: false,
    provinceId: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.provinceId),
  } as FilterQuery<interfaces.ICity>,
};
const query: PipelineStage[] = [match];
const cities = await cityModel.aggregate(query);
```